# How to call service class inside the .ts File in Angular 10

Tags: angular

this is my apiUrl.ts file. Please check.

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

export const url = {
    //Reservation
    getstores: environment.apiUrl + 'company/public/getstores',
    getPublicstores: environment.apiUrl + 'company/public/getPublicstores',
}
```

this is my service file config.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable( )
export class ConfigService {
private appConfig;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadConfig(){
  return this.http.get('./assets/config.json')
  .toPromise()
  .then(res =>{
    this.appConfig = res;
    console.log(res);
  });
  }


  getConfig(){
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

I need to access my service inside the

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the apiUrl and the service is running properly. Then to call the service method from a component.ts file:

```
    constructor(private service: ConfigService){}
    
    callService(): void {
        this.service.loadConfig().subscribe(response => {
            //do something with the response
        });

    }
```

Comment: apiUrl.ts file is not a component. Its just a .ts file. That is the problem for me.

Comment: Then you have to change it to a service.

Comment: can u tell me that change in the service